# Comparing classes in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to python, and while doing some exercises, I needed to compare 2 classes in an html site. I.E. I have the same item, a button, which has a class name when it isn't active, and another one when is active.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
item_class1 = Class name 
item_class2 = Class name

if webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('button').class == item_class1
  DoSomething
elif webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('button').class == item_class
  DoSomethingElse
```

The `.class` works on Ruby, not on Python, there's a function that works like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_attribute('class')`

```
item_class1 = 'Class name'
item_class2 = 'Class name'

if webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button').get_attribute('class') == item_class1 :
   print("something")
elif webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button').get_attribute('class') == item_class2 :
   print("some other thing")
```